# How can I deteremine the "category" for a Facebook event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say a Facebook user creates a Facebook event for "Judy's Paintings - Opening at FooFoo Gallery". You could consider that in the "Art" category. Whereas a sea kyaking trip might fall under "Sports" or "Outdoor".

The [Facebook Graph Api Event endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event) doesn't provide a category attribute. So what's the best way to determine the category?

What we've tried so far:

1. Textual analysis of the name or description attributes of the event. If an event has "music" in the name, it's hopefully about music. You could also use more sophisticated NLP to try to determine meaning.
2. Use the venue. The venue attribute is a [Facebook Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page) Graph API endpoint and the page endpoint has a category attribute.
3. Some combination of the above. Even with weighting.

All of the above will produce some wrong categories on a regular basis.

Does anyone have any better ideas on how to determine the category for a Facebook event? Eventbrite and other event providers have category and sub-category attributes for every event. We are hoping there is also some way to get an accurate category for Facebook events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category field for events is available using Graph API V2.4 or newer, so you can show it and maybe complement the information you're showing.
[Facebook Graph API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event)
Since the field is not always filled by the creator of the event, I suggest you show the categories not only for the event but for the owner and place where it happens.

Hope this answer helps you!
ps: It's my first one on StackOverflow.